# How do I correctly append the title of Incumbent to the current office holder?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

it is something as simple as the query below that really gets on my nerves.

Please bear with me.

The query below lists individuals running for office.

If one of the candidates is the current office holder, indicate so by appending the title of Incumbent in parenthesis to his or her name.

I have run the following query in SSMS and got the results that I am looking for but when used with my .net app, it doesn't append the incumbent title to the current office holder.

What am I missing here?

```
WITH    ctePreAgg
            AS (
                SELECT ( ElectionName + ' - ' + CAST(ClosingDate AS VARCHAR(14)) ) electionName
                    ,CASE WHEN Position = 'Member' THEN 'NULL'
                            ELSE Position
                    END AS Position
                    ,CASE WHEN c.CurrentOfficeHolder = 'Incumbent'
                            THEN CandidateName + '(' + c.CurrentOfficeHolder + ')'
                            ELSE CandidateName
                    END AS CandidateName
                    ,c.PositionId
                    ,CurrentOfficeHolder
                    ,AnswerType
                FROM Candidates c
                JOIN Positions p
                    ON c.PositionId = p.PositionId
                JOIN Elections e
                    ON c.ElectionId = e.ElectionId
                WHERE c.ElectionId IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
                GROUP BY Position
                    ,CandidateId
                    ,CandidateName
                    ,c.PositionId
                    ,CurrentOfficeHolder
                    ,AnswerType
                    ,ElectionName
                    ,ClosingDate
                )
    SELECT [ElectionName_Position] = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0 THEN MAX(mh.Position)
                                            ELSE mh.ElectionName
                                        END
            ,CandidateName = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0 THEN MAX(mh.CandidateName)
                                    ELSE ''
                            END
            ,PositionId = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0 THEN mh.PositionId
                                ELSE 0
                            END
            ,CurrentOfficeHolder = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0
                                        THEN MAX(ISNULL(mh.CurrentOfficeHolder, 'NULL'))
                                        ELSE ''
                                    END
            ,AnswerType = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0 THEN MAX(mh.AnswerType)
                                ELSE ''
                            END
        FROM ctePreAgg mh
        GROUP BY ElectionName
            ,PositionId
            WITH ROLLUP
        HAVING GROUPING(mh.ElectionName) = 0
        ORDER BY mh.ElectionName
            ,GROUPING(mh.PositionId) DESC
            ,mh.PositionID;
```

//SqlDataSource:

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BallotsConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="WITH ctePreAgg
      AS (
           SELECT ( ElectionName + ' - ' + CAST(ClosingDate AS VARCHAR(14)) ) electionName
               ,CASE WHEN Position = 'Member' THEN ''
                     ELSE Position
                END AS Position
               ,CASE WHEN c.CurrentOfficeHolder = 'Incumbent' THEN CandidateName + '(' + c.CurrentOfficeHolder + ')'
                     ELSE CandidateName
                END AS CandidateName
               ,c.PositionId
               ,AnswerType
            FROM Candidates c
            JOIN Positions p
                ON c.PositionId = p.PositionId
            JOIN Elections e
                ON c.ElectionId = e.ElectionId
            WHERE c.ElectionId IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
            GROUP BY Position
               ,CandidateId
               ,CandidateName
               ,c.PositionId
               ,CurrentOfficeHolder
               ,AnswerType
               ,ElectionName
               ,ClosingDate
         )
SELECT [ElectionName_Position] = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0 THEN MAX(mh.Position)
                                      ELSE mh.ElectionName
                                 END
       ,CandidateName = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0 THEN MAX(mh.CandidateName)
                             ELSE ''
                        END
       ,PositionId = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0 THEN mh.PositionId
                          ELSE 0
                     END
       ,AnswerType = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0 THEN MAX(mh.AnswerType)
                          ELSE ''
                     END
    FROM ctePreAgg mh
    GROUP BY ElectionName
       ,PositionId
        WITH ROLLUP
    HAVING GROUPING(mh.ElectionName) = 0
    ORDER BY mh.ElectionName
       ,GROUPING(mh.PositionId) DESC
       ,mh.PositionID;">
           <SelectParameters>
           <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="ElectionId" Type="Int32" Name="ElectionId" DefaultValue="0" />
          </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: You'll likely want to add the .net code too, so folks can check for variances in the query.

Comment: Best thing to do, is to wrap code that works in SP and call that SP from .NET

Comment: @JiggsJedi, sure. Please see above.

Thanks also Vladimir. I will be doing that once I can certify this at least works as embedded.

Comment: You are missing `,CurrentOfficeHolder = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0 THEN MAX(ISNULL(mh.CurrentOfficeHolder, 'NULL'))  ELSE ''  END` from your .NET

Comment: Also, in the first SELECT, at the end you are missing `CurrentOfficeHolder` between `c.PositionID` and `AnswerType` - but its in the group by.  You're not comparing apples to apples here.

Comment: best thing you can do right now is to delete code from .NET and insert code from SSMS

Comment: Also, I'd consider a view instead of a SP so you can pass `WHERE c.ElectionId IN ( 1, 2, 3 )` easier from the front end.  Passing that condition to a SP will likely end up needing dynamic sql.

Comment: Not really you can pass `1,2,3` as `VARCHAR` and than turn it into a table. so you can do `WHERE c.ElectionID in (select id from @myTable)`

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance.

@VladimirOselsky, thanks for solution, `You are missing ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing column `,CurrentOfficeHolder = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0 THEN MAX(ISNULL(mh.CurrentOfficeHolder, 'NULL'))  ELSE '' END` from your .NET that you have in your SQL Code. You probably just copied the code over before you finished working on it. That is the perfect reason to keep the code in one place and SP is the perfect place for it.